# href in <ion-item> breaks when showing a modal window

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**Please read edit 2 as it contains the updated error**

I've got an ng-repeat like this:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="ship in ships" href="#app/ships/{{ship.id}}">
            {{ship}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

When you first load the page the ion-items `href` work as they should. The error occurs when you add new data to the list. The href element stops working and the items are un-clickable. Refreshing the page fixes the `href`

The new data added shows up in the list correctly, with the correct fields and values.

Is this a bug or is there something I have to do to refresh the list?

**EDIT**

I'm using SQLite to save and retrieve my data, also using the factory wrapper found here:  https://gist.github.com/jgoux/10738978

Adding more code:

For adding a new ship I just open a modal window with input fields and a submit button.

```
    // Called when the form is submitted
    $scope.createShip = function (ship) {
        shipFactory.saveShip(ship)
            .then(function () {
                $scope.shipModal.hide();
                updateScope();
                $scope.newship = {};
            });
    };
```

Updating the scope

```
    function updateScope() {
        shipFactory.getAllShips().then(function (ships) {
            $scope.ships = ships;
        });
    }
```

**EDIT 2**
After being unable to recreate the problem in a plunker. I learned that it is the modal that is causing the error. Opening then closing the modal causes the error (no saving).

Modal code:

```
    // Create and load the Modal
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-ship.html', function (modal) {
        $scope.shipModal = modal;
    }, {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    });

    // Open our new ship modal
    $scope.newShip = function () {
        $scope.shipModal.show();
    };

    // Close the new ship modal
    $scope.closeNewShip = function () {
        $scope.shipModal.hide();
    };
```

I have tried adding `$scope.shipModal.remove();` but the links are still broken. Creating a 'Drag' event fixes all the links. For example: Dragging the navigation menu to the view.

Comment: could you post a fiddle ?

Comment: should work, how are you adding the data? not enough info here

Comment: I seem to be unable to recreate the problem in plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/8wEJIxAymUDwQRhBrNda?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I finally fixed my problem. Although I don't fully understand why it would matter, the error occurs because of where I placed the `<button>` element.

If the button is placed inside a `<ion-nav-buttons>` tag, the error occurs.

```
<!--This doesn't work-->
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-circled" ng-click="newShip()"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Placing the button anywhere inside the `<ion-content>` tag has worked as expected.

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    ...
    <button ng-click="newShip()">New ship</button>
</ion-content>
```